# How to use ref returned from Composition API in Options API?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am running a `setup()` method to import an external component which only works with the Options API. Therefore once the imports have taken place, I then need to configure the component using Options API `data`.

How can I access the returned `ref` values from `setup()` within the `data` area of Options API? This is what I mean:

```
setup() {
    const IsBrowser = typeof window !== 'undefined';
    let EssentialsPlugin = ref(null);
    if (IsBrowser) {
      import('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials').then(module => EssentialsPlugin.value = module);
    }

return {
 EssentialsPlugin
},

data() {
return { 
CKEditorConfig:  {
    plugins: [
      EssentialsPlugin   // Needs to be the EssentialsPlugin returned from setup()
]
```

If I run the above code, I get the error: `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: EssentialsPlugin is not defined`.

In this case `CKEditor5` only works with the Options API in Vue. It cannot be configured in Composition API for the [foreseeable future](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue/issues/172). Therefore how can I configure it in Options API with ref values from Composition API `setup()`?

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use the Options API for `data`, it seems most sensible to use a lifecycle hook too:

```
data: () => ({
  isBrowser: typeof window !== 'undefined',
  CKEditorConfig: {
    plugins: []
  }
}),
created() {
  if (this.isBrowser) {
    import('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials')
    .then(module => this.CKEditorConfig.plugins.push(module));
  }
}
```

Comment: Can I access the `ref` from `setup()` within the Options API?

Comment: You could store one in a separate module (or Vuex) and retrieve it inside a lifecycle hook / method

Comment: okay, so to confirm they are not directly accessible within Options API, but *are* accessible in the template?

Comment: I guess you could put it that way.  It's simply that `setup` has no appropriate `this` to attach the ref to, which is how options are accessed in the options api.